# jQuery Gallery - Why does the large image open in another window?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery gallery here: http://encoreazalea.com/ee/the-collection/in-the-landscape

When you click on one of the thumbnails the larger image is supposed to display to the left in the preview image area. However, it opens in another window.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="preview">
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape16.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape15.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape14.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape12.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape13.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape11.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape10.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape9.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape8.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape6.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape7.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
<img id="photo_large" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape5.jpg" class="gallery" alt="photo gallery" />
</div>

</div><!-- end #content-hub -->

<div id="sidebar">
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape16.jpg" title="Landscape16"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape16_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape15.jpg" title="Landscape15"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape15_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape14.jpg" title="Landscape14"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape14_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape12.jpg" title="Landscape12"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape12_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape13.jpg" title="Landscape13"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape13_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape11.jpg" title="Landscape11"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape11_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape10.jpg" title="Landscape10"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape10_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape9.jpg" title="Landscape9"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape9_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape8.jpg" title="Landscape8"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape8_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape6.jpg" title="Landscape6"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape6_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape7.jpg" title="Landscape7"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape7_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
<a href="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape5.jpg" title="Landscape5"><img class="gallery" src="http://encoreazalea.com/ee/landscape-gallery/landscape5_tn.jpg" alt="photo gallery"  /></a>
</div><!-- end #sidebar -->
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:has(img.gallery)").click(function() {
        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
        var caption = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#photo_large").attr({ src: largePath});
        $("#caption1").text(caption);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

I could use some eyes with a better prescription to look at this and help me see what I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: the end-tags are wrong `  /></a>` . do this `  ></a>` or this `  />`. i don't know if that's the error but it's a start

Comment: `ID`'s should be unique.. all your images have the same ID

Comment: Thanks. changed it to class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your page is giving a scripting error. So you need to find and fix it. It fails before loading dropmenu object so the rest of the scripts are not working.

Use a editor that checks javascript syntax or check your codes in jsfiddle's js lint feature.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks yahyaE. I found that the link to the other script was broken.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It works fine. It's just that it never runs because there are other errors on the page. Take a look at the error console. If you execute the snippet above in the console, it works.

Comment: Hi Tom, it says: $("#main-nav").dropmenu is not a function. How did I fix that? Is there a conflict between the two?